# MouseDoubleClick-CommandBinding for WPF-ToolKit's DoubleUpDown not working?

Tags: wpf, commandbinding

I'm using the DoubleUpDown UserControl from the Extended WPF Toolkit in my current project. Now I have to bind a RelayCommand to the DoubleClick event of that DoubleUpDown, but it is not working. I've assigned that DoubleClick to all kinds of different UserControls so far and usually it was working fine or sometimes I had to wrap it into an empty UserControl-Element which would then hold the CommandBinding, but so far I always got it working.

This is what I tried so far:

```
                            <UserControl Grid.Row="7"
                                     Grid.Column="0">
                            <xctk:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding EditableDevice.SelectedLoadReceptor.DecimalPlaces,
                                            UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,
                                            Mode=TwoWay, FallbackValue='1'}"
                                               FormatString="F0"
                                               Minimum="0"
                                               Maximum="10">
                                <xctk:DoubleUpDown.InputBindings>
                                    <MouseBinding Command="{Binding EditDeviceCommand}"
                                                  Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" />
                                </xctk:DoubleUpDown.InputBindings>
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="LeftDoubleClick">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding EditDeviceCommand}" />
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </xctk:DoubleUpDown>
                                <UserControl.InputBindings>
                                <MouseBinding Command="{Binding EditDeviceCommand}"
                                              Gesture="LeftDoubleClick" />
                            </UserControl.InputBindings>
                        </UserControl>
```

I'm usually fine with using the InputBindings, but not with the DoubleUpDown...
I wonder what is causing the issue. Does anyone here have an idea or a workaround?

Regards

Ralf

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, still couldn't figure out what is wrong here. In the meantime I'll just use CodeBehind where ever possible by using the regular MouseDoubleClick-Event.